# Reading a CSV file and doing an action

Tags: python-3.x, csv

i have a csv file that gets populated with 3 lines a day. As the day starts it has none, then 1, 2, and 3. I want my code to go through the lines and do an action based if there is something written to the line or not regardless of whats there. The issue im having is that it will read line 1 & 3 and execute just fine, but not line 2.

```
CSV NAME - User1.csv
CSV EXAMPLE:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

My Code:

```
import csv
import itertools
while 1:
    z = 'User1.csv'
    RUN1 = False
    RUN2 = False
    with open(z, 'r') as f:
        Line = csv.reader(f)
        for Line in itertools.islice(f, 1, 2):
            print('newline2')
            RUN1 = True
        if RUN1 == False:
            for Line in itertools.islice(f, 0, 1):
                print('newline1')
                RUN2 = True
            if RUN2 == False:
                print('newline0')   
    break
```

I will also accept complete rewrites to the code if you could give a brief explanation as to why you wrote it this way so i can better learn python.

SOLVED! Thanks to a_guest comment.

Working code is:

```
import csv
import itertools
while 1:
    z = 'User1.csv'
    RUN1 = False
    RUN2 = False
    with open(z, 'r') as f:
        Line = csv.reader(f)
        for Line in itertools.islice(f, 1, 2):
            print('newline2')
            RUN1 = True
        if RUN1 == False:
            with open(z, 'r') as f:
                for Line in itertools.islice(f, 0, 1):
                    print('newline1')
                    RUN2 = True
                if RUN2 == False:
                    print('newline0')   
    break
```

As a_guest said you have to reset the file pointer which i did with adding again with open(z, 'r') as f: and that has fixed it. Feel free to keep posting to this question with other methods to help others with very similar problems.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. In your code you do `csv.reader(f)` which reads in the file, so subsequent uses of `f` won't be effective without resetting the file pointer.

Comment: you might want to avoid reusing the name `Line` within the loops; it can cause confusing bugs and decreases readability. Also, are you sure you need the `while` loop at all? It looks like you always `break` after a single iteration.